# Preserve formatting with json

Tags: php, json, datatables

I have formatted data in Mysql database as following:

```
[start]
do this
[working]
do that
and thad
not this
[end]
do this
and this
```

I get the data with this PHP script:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ....");
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

then I show it in the frontend with:

```
json[0].columnName
```

and what I get is this:

```
[start] do this [working] do that and thad not this [end] do this and this
```

I think the formatting is lost because of using json. Is it possible to preserve formatting as it is in the database to the frontend? Thank you

Comment: this is not clear , browsers should display json normally , kindly make sure that you don't use any browsers extensions to re-format the output

Comment: What is the exact output in the page DOM?  Carriage returns don't do anything in HTML.  Are you looking for the `<br>` tag?  The `<pre>` tag?  Something else?

Comment: `columnName` database data-type is varchar or text ?

Comment: @hassan: I tested it in several browsers, no formatting plugins or extensions were installed.

Comment: @David: you're right. I see the correct formatting in the DOM, but there are no <br> tags, so it is displayed in one line. Really great point. Is it possible to add somehow <br> in the end of each line? Thanks

Comment: @Ronak Dhoot, varchar(2000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried simulating you issue at local

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","stackoverflow");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM data");
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
?>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
console.log(data    );
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data[0].Location.split('\n').join('<br>');
</script>
```

**output as expected**:

```
[start]
do this
[working]
do that
and thad
not this
[end]
do this
and this
```

So you need to do `json[0].columnName.split('\n').join('<br>')` in your `js` code :)